# How to Setup API Environment in Node

Tags: node.js

I'm building a Node.js REST API.  I have a repository which will hold this REST API code.

I want to be able to test my API.  For now I'll just test via Express and make GET requests to start but I want my express stuff in a separate project because a REST API isn't gonna have any web app portion.

I'm using Webstorm.  So right now I have created a gitHub repo to hold the API which I'll expose REST endpoints.

I want to create a new project also again that will be a Node-Express project for the purpose of pulling in the REST API and consume it.  I am also doing this in a seperate project because I don't want my Express stuff checked into my REST API repo, it doesn't belong there.  I am just using Express for testing stuff.

I realize I can later test my REST endpoints headless, but right now I just wanna get started and figure that out later and just going with an Express project to somehow consume my other API REST project.

I'm not quite sure on a few things, as I come from a .NET enviornment and no longer a .NET developer.  Here are some questions I have:

**My Question**: If I have my Node Express project open in Webstorm, how would I "include" or "require" my rest-api?  Would I somehow npm it down?  But my REST api is not public.  Would I just branch my git REST API repo down, then what?  How would I include it into my seperate Express App project?

Or...do people usually still add express to their REST API projects anyway, maybe it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `npm link` to link a local package

```
$ cd main-project
$ npm link ../path/to/web-api
```

Then in your main project, you can `require` it as you would any other module

---

If you don't intend on publish it, the package.json in your web-api should have

```
{
  "private": true
}
```